# A problem on left Fredholm Operator..

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was reading Fredholm Operators from the book "A course in Functinal Analysis " by J.B Conway. There I got stuck with the following problem.

Let $A\in B(\mathcal H)$. Show that $A(\mathcal M)$ is closed for every closed subspace $\mathcal M$ of $\mathcal H$ iff $A$ has finite rank or $A$ is left fredholm.

I was able to prove that if $A$ is either of finite rank or left fredholm then $A(\mathcal M)$ is closed for every closed subspace $\mathcal M$ of $\mathcal H$. But, I don't know how to prove the other direction . Any help will be appriciated.